# How to account for different screen sizes when writing layout code programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm creating the screen for a login screen, I first tried to build using the storyboard, but it got really confusing very fast. So I jumped to the code, the code I wrote is for an Image, Text, two text fields, and three buttons to show in a simple view similar to a stack view.

Here's an example of two different on the right is the iPhone SE and on the left is the iPhone XR.

[image]

The layout looks fine for the SE but really small for the XR. How do I account for the screen changes so that the UI looks the same on all devices?

Here's the code I used for adding the constraints programmatically:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Round the edges
    Login.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    Register.layer.cornerRadius = 4

    logo.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    logo.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    logo.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    logo.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    logo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 90).isActive = true
    logo.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    letsloginTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    letsloginTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    letsloginTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: logo.bottomAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true

    emailTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    emailTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    emailTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    emailTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180).isActive = true
    emailTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    //emailTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: letsloginTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true


    passwordTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    passwordTextField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    passwordTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180).isActive = true
    passwordTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    passwordTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: emailTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true

    Login.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    Login.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    Login.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    Login.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    Login.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: passwordTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: 60).isActive = true

    Register.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    Register.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    Register.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    Register.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    Register.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: Login.bottomAnchor, constant: 60).isActive = true

    // set delegates
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    //GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()

}
```

Comment: you may set Y point from bottom to up.

Comment: Using storyboard will provide easy options to introduce variations for every constraint based on the screen width and height. You could use that instead of writing in code

Comment: Used constraints on the storyboard and I've made some progress, basically, I want a uniform feel (similar amount of spacing, and the look) on the devices regardless of the screen sizes. Here's the [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/PiMP409) with an annotation to give a brief idea

Answer (score -1):

You could set the width of the views relative to the screen width like to following:

```
let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.3
emailTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
```

and then you set a ratio for your views. for eg: the height is 1:2 the width

```
emailTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width * 0.5).isActive = true
```

Change the values according to your need.

Answer (score -1):

I strongly suggest getting into `XCode Interface Builder`:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/developer-tools/interface-builder

Furthermore, you need to change your way of thinking how to setup an UI for a mobile Device. 
For example: In your case this means instead of defining `width` constraints for the `Login` and `Register` Button - you may define `leading` and `trailing` constraints from the Button-border to the border of the `UIViewController` and perhaps just set a fixed  `height` constraint for them. This will make the Buttons dynamically adapt to the Device.

The next suggestion would be to avoid layouting this elements within code. `Interface Builder` makes it really easy to define these layouts and you will get a lot of handy features for free, furthermore it also can handle more complex layouts. Your code will become unmanageable and hard to read/change if the UI will get more complex. Furthermore it will introduce a lot of Boilerplate code.

Answer (score -2):

In this case you need to playing with screen size.

**1. Get screen width**

`let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

**2. Set margin of button (left, right)**

`let margin = 60`

**Note :** left margin = 30, right margin = 30 total Margin = 60, you can change margin as per your design requirements.

**3. Set our button size**

**New code**

`Register.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:screenWidth - margin).isActive = true`

**Your old code**

`Register.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true`

Note : This is only for portrait mode.

Comment: Here is share only example, not whole code just like spoon feeding, this is just logic for how to handle it.